# Downloading byte array as PDF in Angular

Tags: angular, pdf

I have read several StackOverflow posts related to this, but have yet to get it to work.

My backend is a .NET Core app, and it returns a `byte[]` for me to download the PDF. This is the returned data, first by just calling the API normally and second by setting the return type to `blob`:

[image: pdf card data return data]

The two calls are like this:

```
this.http.get('/my/pdf/url').subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

and

```
this.http.get('/my/pdf/url', { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

In both cases, I take the return data and send it to a service that uses the FileSaver package to save the file. For the first example, I tried saving the file like this:

```
saveFile(buffer: any, fileName: string, fileType: string) {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: fileType });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName);
}
```

It takes the data from the API, converts it to a blob, and then tries to save it. For the `fileType`, I've tried `'application/pdf'` and `'application/octet-stream'`, neither one works. The second example I tried to save like this:

```
savePdf(blob: Blob, fileName: string) {
    FileSaver.saveAs(<any>blob, fileName);
}
```

Neither of these functions work, however. A file is downloaded, but when you open it, there's an error and nothing is displayed.

I'm not sure what else to try, but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning `StreamActionResult` (or similar `ActionResult`) from ASP.NET Core WebAPI, then you should be able to retrieve filename and file type from HTTP response.

1. Create a helper function which retrieves fileName and fileType from HTTP response

```js
export interface DownloadedFile {
  blob: Blob;
  fileName: string;
}

export function extractFileNameAndBlob(
  httpResponse: HttpResponse<ArrayBuffer>
): DownloadedFile {
  const headers = httpResponse.headers;
  const contentDisposition = headers.get("Content-Disposition");

  if (contentDisposition == null) {
    throw new Error(`Server Error: Cannot retrieve file name.
    Either Content-Dispostion header is not available or it is not exposed using Access-Control-Expose Header.`);
  }

  const fileNameItem = contentDisposition
    .split(";")
    .map(item => item.trim())
    .find(item => item.toLowerCase().startsWith("filename="));
  if (fileNameItem == null) {
    throw new Error(`Server didn't send a filename`);
  }

  let fileName = fileNameItem.split("=")[1];
  if (fileName.startsWith('"'))
    fileName = fileName.substring(1, fileName.length - 1);

  const contentType = headers.get("Content-Type");
  const blob = new Blob([httpResponse.body], { type: contentType });
  return {
    blob: blob,
    fileName: fileName
  };
}
```

2. Call WebAPI from angular Service

```js
//  Angular Service
@Injectable()
export class DownloadsService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public downloadPDF(downloadUrl: string): Observable<DownloadedFile> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(downloadUrl, { responseType: "arraybuffer", observe: "response" })
      .pipe(
        map((httpResponse: HttpResponse<ArrayBuffer>) =>
          extractFileNameAndBlob(httpResponse)
        )
      );
  }
}
```

3. In component, call that service, subscribe to the http response and save the file using [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) npm library

```js
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

private someMethod(): void {
 this.downloadsService.downloadPDF('/my/pdf/url').subscribe({
   next: downloadedFile => {
    saveAs(downloadedFile.blob, downloadedFile.fileName);
   }
 });
}
```